# User input accepted whether they input uppercase OR lowercase in C++

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase

Absolute beginner here (FIRST POST) and I am just about finished an assignment where I have had to create a program that lets the user create employee wages slip and then displays them by searching by Surname, Forename, Employee Number, etc.

I am having a problem where If I create a record for Nancy Davidson for e.g. I can output this record properly if I search for EXACTLY Nancy or Davidson. If I search for nancy or davidson it doesn't find it.

I am using a struct to store each employee details, writing them to a data file then reading that file to display the record.

Is there a way that I can get the record to still display even if I search for NAncY?

This my code for my Search By Surname function:

```
    //Record search by employee SURNAME only
void searchSurname(Employee data[], int row)
{
    string surname, again;
    double wholeTot=0, wholeNet=0;
    again = "y";

    while (again=="y"||again=="Y")
    {
        row=0;
        bool found = false;
        clrscr();
        cout << "Please enter Employee SURNAME : ";
        Input(surname);
        clrscr();
        cout << "Surname Search results for " << surname << ". \n\n\n";
        readFile (data, row);
        int stop=row;
        for ( row = 0; row < (stop) ; row++ )
            if (surname == data[row].surname)
            {
                deconvertDate(data[row].date);
                cout << "   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl 
                    << "   # Employee Number - " << RIGHT(19,2) << data[row].empnum << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Employee Surname - " << RIGHT(18,2) << data[row].surname << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Employee Forename - " << RIGHT(17,2) << data[row].forename << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Department Number - " << RIGHT(17,2) << data[row].dept << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Normal Hours Worked - " << RIGHT(15,2) << data[row].hours << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Overtime Hours Worked - " << RIGHT(13,2) << data[row].ohours << " #" << endl 
                    << "   # Pay Rate - " << RIGHT(26,2) << data[row].rate << " #" << endl
                    << "   # Gross Pay - " << RIGHT(25,2) << data[row].grosspay << " #" << endl
                    << "   # Tax - " << RIGHT(31,2) << data[row].tax << " #" << endl
                    << "   # National Insurance - " << RIGHT(16,2) << data[row].natin << " #" << endl
                    << "   # Total Deductions - " << RIGHT(18,2) << data[row].totalDeduct << " #" << endl
                    << "   # Net Pay - " << RIGHT(27,2) << data[row].net << " #" << endl
                    << "   # Week Ending - " << RIGHT(23,2) << data[row].date << " #" << endl 
                    << "   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl << endl << endl;
                wholeTot+=data[row].grosspay;
                wholeNet+=data[row].net;

                cout << "The total recorded GROSS PAY of " << data[row].surname << " is :" << wholeTot << endl;
                cout << " and the total recorded NET PAY is :" << wholeNet << endl << endl;

                found = true;
            }
            else
                if (found = false)
                {
                    cout << "No results found for that SURNAME!" << endl;
                }
```

Comment: If you could provide a small sample of the code that shows the problem and compiles it will allow us to better help you. The simple answer is to do a upper of lower case case conversion when comparing but without code we can not provide more than that.

Comment: Capitalize all names when you store them. Capitalize the search input before searching. That's it.

Comment: The best way is to convert the text you're comparing to upper or lower case upon comparison (=> you store and siplay them as you wish to, but you compare them all in lower/uppercase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `std::equal` for the comparison, you can give it
a fourth argument with a comparitor.  Just write a comparator
which does case insensitive comparison:

```
struct CaseInsensitiveCmp
{
    bool operator()( char lhs, char rhs ) const
    {
        return ::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( lhs ) )
            == ::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( rhs ) );
    }
};
```

(This uses the one argument `tolower` function in `<ctype.h>`,
which is the simplest solution for a beginner.  In production
code, of course, you'd use the `std::ctype` facet in
`<locale>`.)

Answer (score 3):

The trick is usually to convert both the stored record and the user input record in either lower case or upper case. For this you can use [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/75634/) or [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to do case-insensitive comparison.  `strcasecmp` might be a good start: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp

Comment: Which, of course, only works on Posix platforms (unless you write `strcasecmp` yourself).